# definition of of Breuil-Kisin modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, hodge-theory, galois-representations

I want to closely understand the definition of category of Breuil-Kisin modules and its category .
I am a new guest in the topic. So need your help

Comment: Why did you delete the specific questions you had? Now the question is too broad, so I retracted my upvote.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I am sorry but no one answered it. More importantly, my own question was liable to plagiarism (3%) to my own small research paper. That is why I deleted it. I think this does not offend me.